# Visual Basic Button is deactivated

Tags: vba, outlook, vbe

I´m using Outlook 2013 on Windows 2010. The Visual Basic Button is disabled in Outlook.
I tested the information with the Trust Center and the Macro settings, but no changes.
How can I activate the VBA button to write macros?

I have the developer tab active, otherwise I couldn't see that the VBA editor button is deactivated.
I cannot activate the VBA editor button in the developer tab so that I can start the VBA editor. I tried macro security.
What else do I have to do / set to activate the VBA editor?

Comment: turn your developers tab on

Comment: This looks like a guide [How to Run VBA Code in Your Outlook](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/run-vba-code-outlook/)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you see "Microsoft VBA for Outlook Addin" from File | Options | Add-Ins

More information:

- How to fix missing add-in in Outlook 2019, 2016, 2013, 2010 or Office 365
  https://www.techhit.com/how-to/fix-missing-add-in-outlook-2016-2013-2010/
- How to Fix Inactive Outlook Add-ins
  https://www.outlook-apps.com/inactive-outlook-add-ins/